# How can I create a new object with multiple methods?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to follow this tutorial here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/design-your-own-mobile-game/ and I am stuck on the second part. (2. A Blank Canvas)

I am not sure where to put the POP.Draw object. Does it go inside of the var POP{} brackets where the other objects are created? I've tried keeping it inside, outside, and in the init function which I don't think makes sense. The purpose is to create methods within the new Draw object so they can be called later to create pictures in the canvas.

Here is my current code. It is the same as the one in the link:

```
var POP = {
  //setting up initial values
  WIDTH: 320,
  HEIGHT: 480,
  // we'll set the rest of these
  //in the init function
  RATIO: null,
  currentWidth: null,
  currentHeight: null,
  canvas: null,
  ctx: null,

  init: function() {
    //the proportion of width to height
    POP.RATIO = POP.WIDTH / POP.HEIGHT;
    //these will change when the screen is resized
    POP.currentWidth = POP.WIDTH;
    POP.currentHeight = POP.HEIGHT;
    //this is our canvas element
    POP.canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    //setting this is important
    //otherwise the browser will
    //default to 320x200
    POP.canvas.width = POP.WIDTH;
    POP.canvas.width = POP.HEIGHT;
    //the canvas context enables us to
    //interact with the canvas api
    POP.ctx = POP.canvas.getContext('2d');

    //we need to sniff out Android and iOS
    // so that we can hide the address bar in
    // our resize function
    POP.ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    POP.android = POP.ua.indexOf('android') > -1 ? true : false;
    POP.ios = (POP.ua.indexOf('iphone') > -1 || POP.ua.indexOf('ipad') > -1) ? true : false;

    //we're ready to resize
    POP.resize();
    POP.Draw.clear();
    POP.Draw.rect(120, 120, 150, 150, 'green');
    POP.Draw.circle(100, 100, 50, 'rgba(225,0,0,0.5)');
    POP.Draw.text('Hello WOrld', 100, 100, 10, "#000");

  },

  resize: function() {
    POP.currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    //resize the width in proportion to the new height
    POP.currentWidth = POP.currentHeight * POP.RATIO;
    //this will create some extra space on the page
    //allowing us to scroll past the address bar thus hiding it
    if (POP.android || POP.ios) {
      document.body.style.height = (window.innerHeight + 50) + 'px';
    }

    //set the new canvas style width and height note:
    //our canvas is still 320 x 400 but we're essentially scaling it with css
    POP.canvas.style.width = POP.currentWidth + 'px';
    POP.canvas.style.height = POP.currentHeight + 'px';

    //we use a timeout here because some mobile browsers
    //don't fire if there is not a short delay
    window.selfTimeout(function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    })

    //this will create some extra space on the page
    //enabling us to scroll past the address bar
    //thus hiding it
    if (POP.android || POP.ios) {
      document.body.style.height = (window.innerHeight + 50) + 'px';
    }

  }

};
window.addEventListener('load', POP.init, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', POP.resize, false);

//abstracts various canvas operations into standalone functions
POP.Draw = {
  clear: function() {
    POP.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, POP.WIDTH, POP.HEIGHT);
  },

  rect: function(x, y, w, h, col) {
    POP.ctx.fillStyle = col;
    POP.ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  },

  circle: function(x, y, r, col) {
    POP.ctx.fillStyle = col;
    POP.ctx.beginPath();
    POP.ctx.arc(x + 5, y + 5, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    POP.ctx.closePath();
    POP.ctx.fill();
  },

  text: function(string, x, y, size, col) {
    POP.ctx.font = 'bold' + size + 'px Monospace';
    POP.ctx.fillStyle = col;
    POP.ctx.fillText(string, x, y);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I didn't realize but the completed code is on the webpage. I downloaded it and looked at the example for answers.

I solved the issue by placing the POP.Draw.clear, POP.Draw.rect methods before calling the POP.resize() method. I'm not really sure why the order matters, but it does.